# angular await does not wait for the function to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, async-await

I am calling a async function from cordova plugin. However the await does not really work.

```
export class MationLiteService implements IgatewayService {
  async getGroupAllInfo(gatewayId: string, account: string, decryptedpasswd: string) {

// some codes
        return await cordova.plugins.MationPlugin.getGroupAllInfo(data, async (response) => {

        const json: JSON = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log('responseaaaaa:' + response);
        return json;
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('error: ' + error);
      });
  }
}
```

here is the gateway manager class

```
export class GatewayManagerService {
 public  getGroupAllInfo(gatewayType: string, gatewayId: string, account: string, decryptedpasswd: string) {
    return this.gatewayFactoryService.getGateway(gatewayType).getGroupAllInfo(gatewayId, account, decryptedpasswd);
  }
}
```

this is how i call it

```
  async getAllInfo2(){
     this.facadaService.GetGatewayManagerService().getGroupAllInfo('mation-lite', this.zifan, 'admin', '5555').then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
     });
    //await this.facadaService.GetGatewayManagerService().test('mation-lite');

  }
```

it gave me undefined when i try to print the response.

Comment: What type does `getGroupAllInfo` return? This is Typescript - we like types!

Comment: sorry i am still new to these async functions, the callback will return a string. the function itself wont return anything. But Nicholas Tower's answer works well. i did not understand the concept of promise and callback when i did my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` only works with promises, and it looks like `MationPlugin.getGroupAllInfo` uses a callback for its asynchrony, not a promise. You will need to wrap it in a promise yourself.

```
getGroupAllInfo(gatewayId: string, account: string, decryptedpasswd: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cordova.plugins.MationPlugin.getGroupAllInfo(data, (response) => {
      const json: JSON = JSON.parse(response);
      resolve(json);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
})
```